# C# Debiasing from Good PRNG

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am in need of a "debiased" clamp function, to generate a uniformly-distributed random number from a good PRNG.

Let's assume that `RNG` in the below code is a field containing an instance of a good (or good enough) PRNG such as PCG, Xoshiro, or MT, which produced a reasonably-uniform distribution of random integers.

```csharp
public int GetClamped(int maxnum) {
    // maxnum is totally arbitrary here, and likely not a power of 2
    int cap = int.MaxValue / maxnum * maxnum;
    int r;
    do {
        r = RNG.NextPositiveInt();  // Returns a value in the range [0, int.MaxValue]
    } while (r >= cap);
    return r >= maxnum ? r % maxnum : r;
}
```

I wonder if this can be optimized further, seeing I have 2 divisions and a multiplication there.

---

### About "Debiasing"

Let's say a good PRNG returns a 16-bit value in the range of `[0, 65535]` with a uniform distribution.

If I clamp the value to `1000` and simply use the modulus `%` operator, the values in the range of `[0, 535]` after clamping will appear one time more often than the values in the range of `[536, 999]` (because there is no `65536, 65537 ... 65999`)

This means that a simple clamping using the modulus `%` operator introduces a bias towards the lower range.

The algorithm above tries to find the largest value which will still satisfy the uniform distribution (`64999`) and discards all values above that cap to pull a new value from the PRNG.

The principle is that if `[0, 65535]` is uniform, then a truncated range of `[0, 64999]` will still be uniform. Hence the algorithm name of "unbiased clamping" or "debiased clamping".

Do note that the clamping value `maxnum` is arbitrary; it is not necessarily `1000` (like in this example), but can be any value in accordance to the user's needs. So, a precalculated table of "multiplicative equivalent to division" is simply not practical.

Comment: Why not simply `return RNG.NextPositiveInt() % maxnum`?

Comment: @aepot That will cause a biased output; the lower values will appear more often than the higher values.

Comment: Ok, `return (int)((double)maxnum / int.MaxValue * RNG.NextPositiveInt())` or you may initially generate `double` to reduce conversion complexity. Anyway this one faster than any of the optimistic scenarios applied to the initial solution.

Comment: @aepot Although in theory that should work (scaling the range), in practice performing the floating point division will result in numbers 'not accurately representable' in floating point (e.g., `0.1` -- and integer multiples of -- cannot be represented in floating point accurately). This greatly complicates trying to prove that the scaling does not cause a bias, unlike the simple axiom of "truncating a uniform dist will result in a still-uniform dist". In short, I'd like to stay in the integer land when possible.

Comment: Ok, this makes some noise to RNG making state-based predictability somewhat more complicated (RNG security improvement?). Btw, you're not doing exact computations but random numbers generation. How much CPU time do you want to pay to avoid that noise? What it may affect? Here's no sense to stay in integers, it doesn't worth to introduce polling loop instead of simple FP division+multiplication. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: Do bear in mind that my need is just to clamp the RNG. Another team is in charge of the generation, and their spec is that the resulting RNG must be uniformly-distributed. As long as they fulfill their specs, I am required to ensure that clamping does not change the uniform distribution. There are ... certain industries whose regulatory bodies _require_ a formal proof of uniform distribution. The inaccuracy of FP will cause sawtooth pattern in the distribution, as numbers get shifted to the left or right when the FP cannot accurately represent the scaling.

Comment: Finally, there's this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful <== the speaker did not mince words and explicitly stated that scaling with FP results in **_hilariously_** non-uniform distribution, and he explicitly criticized "people on Stack Overflow recommending this method".

Comment: OK, `return (int)((long)maxnum * RNG.NextPositiveInt() / int.MaxValue))`. Polling the RNG breaks the distribution profile, anyway. Because you're skipping output by the fixed scenario. That's causing a clamping method consequence appear in the genereated output. Benchmark it, get the stats, measure the distribution behavior. Reading books is good but testing is better.

Comment: @aepot any method that does not reject some samples is biased for a fundamental reason: you cannot fairly spread N things over M buckets except in the special case that M divides N. How the spreading is done does not matter, no method can work.

Comment: @harold exactly!